# android SAXparser get element use attribute value

Tags: android, xml, sax

this is xml
[image]

this is SAXhandler
[image]

it will get all img. but I just want get phil_1,phil_2 use name="phil".
Can SAXparser do it? And how to do that.

Comment: can anybody help me ?

Comment: is sAX parsing a requriement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a [SAX filter](http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/books/xmljava/chapters/ch08.html) though honestly that's overkill here. You could easily write something like this instead:

```
if (localName.equals("img")) { // do not ignore case
  if ("phil".equals(attributes.getValue("name")) {
    // do your work...
```